# Python xlib change cursor

Tags: python, xlib, mouse-cursor

How can I set the cursor for the root window (or any other window) in a python application using Xlib?

I have an instance of `display` and `window` (the root window).
Using the C bindings; I could use [XDefineCursor](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XDefineCursor.html) with a cursor I have created with [XCreatePixmapCursor](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/pixmap-and-cursor/XCreatePixmapCursor.html). How do I do the same with the python bindings?

I want to be able to use a default cursor, or a custom cursor.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you want to keep in mind when you need to find the python-xlib equivalent of any libX11 function:

1. Unlike libX11, python-xlib is object-oriented; In this case, `XCreatePixmapCursor()` translates to `pixmap.create_cursor()`.
2. Most python-xlib methods map directly to X11 messages, ie. most helper functions aren't implemented; If you can't find a matching python-xlib method, you'll often want to look at the [libX11 source code](https://github.com/mirror/libX11/) to figure out if the function is just a helper that calls some other function under the hood. In this case, if you look at the [source code of `XDefineCursor()`](https://github.com/mirror/libX11/blob/78851f6a03130e3c720b60c3cbf96f8eb216d741/src/DefCursor.c), you'll see it's actually calling `XChangeWindowAttributes()`, meaning you'll want to use `win.change_attributes()` in python-xlib.

If you want to use `XCreateFontCursor()` to use a cursor from the cursor font, the second guideline again applies: It's calling `XCreateGlyphCursor()` under the hood, which corresponds to `font.create_glyph_cursor()`.

Putting all of that together, here's what you'll get:

```
# Create font cursor
font = display.open_font('cursor')
cursor = font.create_glyph_cursor(font, Xlib.Xcursorfont.crosshair, Xlib.Xcursorfont.crosshair+1, (65535, 65535, 65535), (0, 0, 0))


# Use PIL to load a cursor image and ensure that it's 1-bit as required
im = Image.open('cursor.png').convert('1')
w, h = im.size

# Create pixmap cursor
mask = win.create_pixmap(w, h, 1)
gc = mask.create_gc(foreground=0, background=1)
mask.put_pil_image(gc, 0, 0, im)
cursor = mask.create_cursor(mask, (0, 0, 0), (65535, 65535, 65535), 0, 0)


# Change cursors for given windows
win.change_attributes(cursor=cursor)
```

If you're wondering about the significance of the `+1` in the call to `font.create_glyph_cursor()`, that's explained in the [source code of `XCreateFontCursor()`](https://github.com/mirror/libX11/blob/e835a9dcc3362b5e92893be756dd7ae361e64ced/src/Cursor.c#L39).

Comment: And regarding getting the current cursor font/glyph/bitmap, for when you wish to revert the cursor back, [see here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/e931119a41d0c48d1c544af89768b119b13feb4d/libavdevice/xcbgrab.c#L331-L397)