# I want to hide the cursor movements everywhere

Tags: python, cursor, mouse, python-3.7

I want to add it to my script but I've been looking for hours and didn't come up with an answer yet so I'm making my first post on stackoverflow. I'm looking for a way to hide my cursor, while still tracking the mouse movements and cursor position. I want this to happen everywhere on my windows. I tried Tkinter and Xlib but couldn't find a solution. For Xlib i checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660613/how-do-you-hide-the-mouse-pointer-under-linux-x11) but I'm not sure how to use the XDefineCursor in my code.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke Yeah, i want to add it to my script.

Comment: I checked that post, and tried working with Xlib but I had no luck. I'm not sure how i can use XDefineCursor in my program.

Comment: Done. Thank you very much for the feedback.

Comment: Deleted my comments as they are no longer relevant. I wish you good luck. Would love to see a solution here.

Comment: Hm. What about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554701/python-xlib-change-cursor

Comment: I found how to do it and posted the answer! Thanks again for your help @LydiavanDyke!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529991/disable-or-lock-mouse-and-keyboard-in-python) before, but apparently I didn't try the code. So after trying it, it worked out fine.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer then.